# Show text in the top-right corner, like in docs?

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

The new [twitter-bootstrap docs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html) have a nice interface for delimiting examples.

[image: scrnshot]

**How do I get this same effect, but within the `well`?**

My attempt: http://jsfiddle.net/YdusM/

Comment: Nope, just want the exact same background colour + border as around the text: "Example". So want that in the top left of the `well`. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about that: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YdusM/3/)

Apply `.well:before {...}` instead `.corner_text:before {...}`

**UPDATE:**

Apply 'example element' for specific well-block: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YdusM/10/)

Comment: Thanks, that worked but I have other `well`s on the page which I don't want to get affected by this... how do I do that?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Just use specific class, like: `.example-block:before {...}`

Answer (score 0):

You can just inspect the code in the docs, and you wil find this css, applied to the exmaple wrapper:

```
.bs-docs-example::after {
content: "Example";
position: absolute;
top: -1px;
left: -1px;
padding: 3px 7px;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
background-color: whiteSmoke;
border: 1px solid #DDD;
color: #9DA0A4;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
-moz-border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
}
```

Add something similar as a custom class to your css, or you could even do it in less to use the bootstrap variables and mixins. If you want the text to be addaptable, it would perhaps be better to forget about the :after and adapt this styling a bit to apply it to a specific element holding the text you want and place it inside the wrapper.

**edit:**
For the positioning to work, you should set the wrapper to `position: relative;` as well. Not sure what you are after, but i updated your fiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/YdusM/9/

Comment: Any idea how to modify this for addaptable text ?

Comment: @Oyslo: sure, you would just have to add an extra div with the text for you label, and apply all styling to that (without the `content:` offcourse) with the use of a specific class. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/YdusM/15/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying `:before` to outer div. I made it to `.well` and adjusted the padding top and left to `-20px`..

ie

```
.well:before {
  position: relative;
  content: "Example";
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #9da0a4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
     -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
          border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
}
```

Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YdusM/7/